# FILTER between columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I have thousands of data in 2 columns

First one is ordered by export and the other by latest activity. The export columns has more queries than the latest activity. (can't change the export to the latest activity)

I stuck in finding a way to get all the email addresses from the latest activity and check where they are in the export list.
***And important sidenote: the latest activity list is incomplete at the end of each query. As the example below.***

```
name1@mail.country  name3@mail.c
name2@mail.country  name4@mail.coun
name3@mail.country  name6
name4@mail.country  name1@ma
name6@mail.country  name5@mail.country
name5@mail.country  name2@ma
name10@mail.country 
name3000@mail.country
```

I need to **find** and **keep** all the duplicates and **remove** all the others
So in this case name10@mail.country & name3000@mail.country should be deleted.

Is this something I can do in Sheets automated instead of manually finding each one by `cmd+f`.

I have about 5000 active users I need to filter out.
*fingerscrossed*

The expected result would be that I can exclude everything from the first column based on everything from the second column.

Link for example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PnnBDR8mKn77Jtf6E9Y4fYGlghxxVL9SguCSH3u-bp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. What would the expected results be in your example? Also. Is the question about Excel or Google sheets? Please edit your question.

Comment: *"...exclude everything from the first column based on everything from the second column"* Sorry but it does not make sense. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: The only *"duplicate"* in both your sheet as well as your example is `name5@mail.country`. Is this what you want? BTW, your sheet does not help much :(

Comment: I found the solution with google-apps-script here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682318/copy-row-to-new-sheet-using-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem and maybe the viewers problem can be fixed with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682318/copy-row-to-new-sheet-using-google-apps-script

Comment: While links might be helpful, answers should be self-contained. Please consider adding the relevant parts or a summary of the linked resource. P.S. This question was bumped by Community a few moments ago. It has been bumped by Community 8 times.